# Virtualbox Bluetooth

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox and install windows 11, but I am still unable to activate bluetooth, no button shows to on/off bluetooth.
please guide me for this how to on/off or activate bluetooth.

Comment: You need to understand that a virtual machine only seems the virtual hardware provided by the virtualization software (Virtualbox).

Comment: Does this tutorial work  for you https://scribles.net/enabling-bluetooth-in-virtualbox/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

There are some prerequisites before starting the steps.

- Windows PC with Bluetooth adapter
- Ubuntu installed as VirtualBox guest OS and running on Windows
- VirtualBox Guest Additions installed on Ubuntu guest OS

1. Disable Bluetooth adapter on Windows

   1.1. Launch Device Manager. (Right-click on the Windows icon at the bottom left corner of the desktop, then select *Device Manager*.)

   [image]

   1.2. Disable Bluetooth adapter (right-click on your Bluetooth device and select *Disable device* by toggling Enable/Disable device.)

   [image]
2. Launch Ubuntu

   2.1. Launch Oracle VM VirtualBox.

   2.2. Select your Ubuntu guest and click on the *Start* icon in the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager window.

   [image]
3. Enable Bluetooth Adapter on Windows

   Go back to Device Manager, enable the Bluetooth adapter. (Right-click on the Bluetooth device and select *Enable device*.)

   [image]
4. Enable Bluetooth adapter on Ubuntu (Guest OS)

   4.1. In Oracle VM VirtualBox window, select *Devices* -> *USB* from the top menu bar.

   4.2. Then select Bluetooth adapter to enable.

   [image]
5. Verify

   Check if Bluetooth is enabled in Ubuntu by typing the following command.

   ```
   hciconfig -a
   ```

   If everything is fine, you should be able to see something like in the below example. Be sure it says `UP RUNNING` (line 4 in the below example).

   ```
   $ hciconfig -a
   hci0: Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
       BD Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  ACL MTU: 1021:7  SCO MTU: 240:3
       UP RUNNING 
       RX bytes:1039 acl:0 sco:0 events:54 errors:0
       TX bytes:2435 acl:0 sco:0 commands:54 errors:0
       Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
       Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
       Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
       Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
       Name: 'vm'
       Class: 0x0c0000
       Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
       Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
       HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x8300
       LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x9172
       Manufacturer: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. (72)
   ```

<sub>**Source:** revised from [Enabling Bluetooth in VirtualBox](https://scribles.net/enabling-bluetooth-in-virtualbox/)</sub>